Categorizing Julia set for polynomial
Im reading 2 books(I've attached the corresponding theorems) about the properties of the Julia set for polynomials.
If i do understand correctly we have that the Julia set is:

connected if the orbits of all (finite) critical points are bounded
connected components if some but not all are unbounded
cantor set if all are unbounded

But I'm a little lost on how to actually categorize when I have a concrete polynomial.
Say I'm looking at $P(z)=z^3-3a^2z-2a^3$, it has finite critical points $\pm a$. Where do I go from here to put this into the corresponding category?
Maybe I'm just lacking the knowledge on how to find bounds on iterating polynomials because brute forcing $P^k(\pm a)$ with a computer seems a little tedious if not impossible
milnor: dynamics
Carleson, Gamelin:Complex dynamics


Maybe I'm just lacking the knowledge on how to find bounds on iterating polynomials because brute forcing $P^k(\pm a)$ with a computer seems a little tedious if not impossible.

Nonetheless, that is a fruitful approach and exactly why the field exploded with the advent of widely available computational power. Of course, there's still plenty of theory that guides the computation.
The first thing you might try to do is generate a bifurcation locus for your family of functions. That is, first define
$$
f_{a}(z) = z^3 - 3a^2z - 2a^3.
$$
Then, choose a grid of $a$ values in the complex parameter plane. For each value of $a$ in the grid, iterate $f_{a}$ from both critical values $+a$ and $-a$ and then classify according to whether

Both $+a$ and $-a$ exceed some escape radius (more on that in a minute),
$+a$ escapes but $-a$ does not after some maximum number of iterations,
$-a$ escapes but $+a$ does not after that maximum number of iterations,
neither $+a$ nor $-a$ escape.

You can then color according to which class your parameter $a$ belongs in and, if applicable, the escape time.
Note that there is plenty of theory driving this, starting with the theorem you referenced which tells us that the critical points drive the global structure of the dynamics. Another issue is the escape radius, which for a polynomial
$$
a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0,
$$
can be taken to be
$$
R = \max\left(2,2|a_n|,2\frac{|a_{n-1}|+\cdots+|a_0|}{|a_n|}\right).
$$
Implementing that strategy, I generated the following picture:

In this picture,

Shaded gray indicates that both critical points escaped,
blue indicates that just $+a$ escaped,
red indicates that just $-a$ escaped, and
black indicates that neither escaped.

Note that the image bears a striking resemblance to the Mandelbrot set, which is not too surprising I guess. In particular, the boundary between the regions is very complicated, which suggests that there's probably no quick or simple test to determine the overall structure of the Julia set. Indeed, it's probably computational infeasible for a small set parameter values.
Of course, we can zoom in to help us find parameter values with desired behavior. Here's a closer look at the blue region to the right:

It sure looks like $a=3/4$ should yield a Julia set consisting of infinitely many connected components.  Indeed, here's an image of the Julia set:


Thanks a lot for that detailed answer^^  would you mind sharing how you generated those images? I've actually tried with some naive python but my visuals didn't look anywhere close as good

Sure - glad you like it. I generated the parameter space pictures with Python on my laptop but put the code in this Colab notebook that anyone should be able to view. I think anyone with a Google account should be able to save and run the code as well.
I generated the Julia set with this javascript program that I just happened to already have.
